# Remove leading column values <= 0

Tags: matlab, octave

I have some input such like:

```
a = -1.60400000000000,-0.604000000000000,0.396000000000000,1.39600000000000,2.39600000000000,3.39600000000000,4.39600000000000,5.39600000000000,6.39600000000000,7.39600000000000
```

And I want to remove the columns with a value which is negative / 0.

I have tried the following:

```
a = max(a, 0);
a = a(:,a(:,:)>0);
```

But to no avail.

Any suggestions also using linear indexing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to remove elements (besides reassigning the array) is by assigning `[]` to the elements you want removed.  For a 1D row/column vector

```
a(a<=0) = []
```

It's not clear what is needed for a matrix, but say you want to remove the columns for which all values in that column are negative:

```
a(:,all(a<=0,1)) = []
```

Or if you want to remove columns with any negative values:

```
a(:,any(a<=0,1)) = []
```

In order to treat the *first element/row* of each column as the indicator for removing the entire column:

```
a(:,a(1,:)<=0) = []
```

For example:

```
>> a=rand(5)-0.5
a =
    0.0822   -0.3808    0.0447    0.4937   -0.0954
    0.0407    0.4398    0.1473   -0.2813   -0.0516
    0.3699    0.1456    0.0439   -0.3942   -0.1342
   -0.2352   -0.0205    0.2210   -0.3903    0.2635
   -0.1819    0.1393    0.0225   -0.4364    0.1279
```

```
>> a(:,a(1,:)<=0) = []
a =
    0.0822    0.0447    0.4937
    0.0407    0.1473   -0.2813
    0.3699    0.0439   -0.3942
   -0.2352    0.2210   -0.3903
   -0.1819    0.0225   -0.4364
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. This has helped me to understand  the syntax and concept much more.

Answer (score 2):

for your example you can just use

```
a(a>0)
```